# Passing a list in a function in Python

Tags: python, list, function

I want to create a function which will receive a list, check each element of it and return a new list. If the element is greater than 97, it will put 100 in the new list. Otherwise, it will add three to the number and put it in the new list. At the function I just pass the list. However, when I run it it doesn't return anything.

Here is how I send the list to the function:

```
res=bonus(mark)
```

Here is my function:

```
def bonus(mark):
    new=[]
    for i in range(1,31):
        if (mark[i-1]>97):
            new.append(100)
        else:
            new.append(mark[i-1]+3)
    return new
```

Comment: what hinders you to do it? Format your code correctly - after the def..: you need to indent

Comment: Any error messages? Like `IndexError: list index out of range`? How do you test that `res` hasn't received anything back from the function?

Comment: It doesn't show any error messanges. But, when I try to print res it doesn't show anything. That's why I think it doesn't return anything.

Comment: If you copy your function as it is shown here into a new script, `res` should contain a list. You do something else in the rest of the script. You have to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare the function before calling it.

**For example:**

```
mark = [1,97,3,4,98,6,99,8,9,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]

def bonus(mark):
    new=[]
    for i in range(1,31):
        if (mark[i-1]>97):
            new.append(100)
        else:
            new.append(mark[i-1]+3)
    return new

res=bonus(mark)

print(res)
```

outputs:

```
[4, 100, 6, 7, 100, 9, 100, 11, 12, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 3]
```

Comment: No, that was my mistake when I copied the code here. In my code I have written it like you said. I have changed it here too.

Comment: @MikeJohnson Yeah, I saw that you edited. I then saw the real mistake and edited to show it. Peace

Comment: If the function were not declared, it would return `NameError: name 'bonus' is not defined`

Comment: I have already created the mark list in the main function. I just want to send it in bonus function and create and return a new list.

Comment: @MikeJohnson The mark list was an example so I can show it works. This was tested and that is real output. Just make sure your function declaration `def bonus(mark):` comes before (somewhere above) `res=bonus(mark)`.

Comment: Yes it comes before.

Comment: @MikeJohnson Can you show more of your code please, because I just proved that what you posted works. The problem must be somewhere else.

Comment: @Ivan86 I tried to do exactly what you did, with the difference that I have my own mark list and when I print it it shows [4.0].

Here is how I do it:

    if (average<60):
        res=bonus(mark)
        print(res)

Comment: @MikeJohnson try to do `print(mark)` before calling `res=bonus(mark)`  to see how many elements your list `mark` has. It looks like it has only one element.... and that is `4.0`. Check to see if it is true, you could have a problem with creating the `mark` list.

Comment: @Ivan86 It prints all the elements

Comment: @MikeJohnson please update your question with the output of `print(mark)` and `type(mark)` before you call the `res=bonus(mark)`.

Comment: @Ivan86 Thank you very much for your help. I finally found the problem and solved it. My program is running perfectly.

Comment: @MikeJohnson glad to hear that :) peace

Answer (score 0):

If you go through a list, do not use `range(..)` use `for item in listname:`

```
def bonus(mark):
    new=[]
    for item in mark:  # item will be each element of mark in order, no need to indexaccess
        if (item > 97):
            new.append(100)
        else:
            new.append(item + 3)
    return new
```

Or shorten it to a list comprehension:

```
mark = list(range(80,100))

def bonus(m):
    return [min(100,m+3) for m in mark] # add m+3, if > 100 (for 98,99,100) use 100.

print (mark)
print (bonus(mark))
```

Output:

```
[80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99]
[83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 100, 100]
```